Supabase Local Function on JWT creation
I have a supabase project that is being used for Auth management as well as some simple storage scenarios. I have a hook that runs when a JWT is created and it grabs the user role (from the user_roles table, matched on user uuid) and adds it to the JWT payload. This is read on the frontend JS to for dynamic access control based on what the user role is. This has been working fine on the production supabase application but when I try and set this up on my local supabase instance the JWT is empty.
The database migration grabs the schema and I seed the local db with some data. I can see my custom_access_token_hook function in my local instance. Is there a way to have the hook in my local so that it runs when a JWT is created and I can get my user roles?
Here is the custom_access_token_hook:

  declare
    claims jsonb;
    user_role public.app_role;
  begin
    -- Check if the user is marked as admin in the profiles table
    select role into user_role from public.user_roles where user_id = (event->>'user_id')::uuid;

    claims := event->'claims';

    if user_role is not null then
      -- Set the claim
      claims := jsonb_set(claims, '{user_role}', to_jsonb(user_role));
    else
      claims := jsonb_set(claims, '{user_role}', 'null');
    end if;

    -- Update the 'claims' object in the original event
    event := jsonb_set(event, '{claims}', claims);

    -- Return the modified or original event
    return event;
  end;



This ended up being a config error. I had to change the uri for my hook in the config.toml file. For more information look at this thread.
Here is the hook settings in the config.toml:
# This hook runs before a token is issued and allows you to add additional claims based on the authentication method used.
[auth.hook.custom_access_token]
enabled = true
uri = "pg-functions://postgres/public/custom_access_token_hook"

Then stop your supabase, delete temp folder, start supabase.
